# When can we compute the CDF of the Compound Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Suppose we have a Compound Poisson Process with intensity $\lambda$
$$
            S_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i.
$$
We can compute the formula for the CDF as follows
\begin{align*}
    F_{S_t}(x) = P(S_t \leq x) 
    &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(S_t \leq x \mid N_t = k)P(N_t = k) \\
    & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(\sum_{i=1}^k X_i \leq x)\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t} \\
    & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty F_X^{*k}(x)\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}. \\
\end{align*}
My question is, Is there a known distribution for $X_i$ such that this formula can be explicitly computed? To me the exponential distribution seemed like a promising choice, but I wasn't able to get far with it.

Comment: Compound Poisson distributions are special cases of infinitely divisible distributions. Their characteristic functions can be written in neat form.

Comment: That I know, but this question is more for application purposes. It is easier to compute probabilities with closed form distribution functions instad of approximating them.